# How to use arrow function instead of 'bind' in a helper function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a class, which imports a helper function

```
import {foo} from '../helper/foo';
...
foo(someArg, this.retFunc.bind(this));
```

Which works fine - I call the helper function 'foo', pass it an argument 'someArg' and it calls the retFunc with the proper context for 'this'.

Hoew would I replace the above with an arrow function? When I do the following, retFunc never gets called:

```
foo(someArg, () => this.retFunc);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with

```
foo(someArg, () => this.retFunc)
```

First, the callback function (`() => this.retFunc`) does not call the function, and will only return a function when the callback is called, which is probably not helpful in you example.

However

```
foo(someArg, () => this.retFunc())
```

has another issue, which is that any parameters passed to the callback function will be ignored, and won't be passed to `this.retFunc()`. This can be a good thing, or a bad thing, depending on what you expect `retFunc` to need for parameters.

As you're after a substitute for `.bind(this)` then the appropriate replacement would be to use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to pass any input to your function:

```
foo(someArg, (...args) => this.retFunc(...args))
```

All that said, you're not saving anything by attempting to replace `bind` in this particular example:

```
foo(someArg, this.retFunc.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not called it. Add the `()` part. You have just pass a callback which does not call the function inside it. You can also pass parameters to the *arrow function* as rest parameters and pass it into `retFunc`.

```
foo(someArg, (...rest) => this.retFunc(...rest));
// -----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```